# php---get image path that in a directory using php and show image using HTML

Tags: php

I have a directory to show an image:

```
www\item(directory)
1.gif
```

How can i use PHP to get the image path?

I also want to check if the directory is exist,i get the image path,If not show error.

If I get the image path,I want to show the image using HTML like:

```
<img src="(image path)" style="width:304px;height:228px">
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more information. Your directory above is malformed, so I don't really know what you want here. It also wouldn't help to spell check your question. Welcome to SO. :P

Comment: The path of directory is in (www\item)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you got the image path into a variable > $image_path

Simply do this...

```
<img src="<?php echo $image_path; ?>" style="width:304px;height:228px">
```

Comment: How can i get the image path using php?

Comment: @Rex - Everything you need to get must have a source

Comment: The image is in www\item , i need to using PHP to find it out.

Comment: Because i want to check if the directory is exist

Comment: `if(is_dir('www/item')){}`

Comment: so how can in get the image path in www/item?

Comment: This depends on the current location of your script, and will work if you are currently located in a parent folder to www. example html/index.php... where the dir content of html is (www,xx,yy) etc

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

```
<?php 
$file = "C:\myfile.jpg";
if(file_exists($file)){
        if(is_readable($file)){
        echo '<img src="'.$file.'">';
        }
    }
    else
    {
    // UNABLE TO FIND FILE;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Dear Rex do this,

```
<?php
$path = "www/item";
$folder = opendir($path);
$pic = false;
while(false !== ($file = readdir($folder))){
    $fileName = $path.$file;
    $info = pathinfo($path.$file);
    $ext = strtolower($info['extension']);
    $allowed =array("jpg","bmp","png","gif");
    if(filetype($fileName) == "file"){
        if(in_array($ext,$allowed)){
            echo"
            <div style='display:inline-block'>
            <img src='$fileName' style='width:96px;height:70px;' title='Filename: $file'>
            <a target = '_blank' href='$fileName'>Download</a>
            </div>
            ";
            $pic = true;
            }
        }
    }
if($pic == false){
    echo "There are no images in $path";
    }
?>
```